# VPN on Windows: how can I force only some app / website should use it

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, vpn

I'm behind a corporate proxy which unfortunately is really slow. Especially if I'm working remotely through a VPN. I would like to route Outlook and maybe IE through the VPN while all my CLI Tools, Chrome etc. keep using the normal connection.

How can I achieve such a setup?

Comment: I have seen this before. Ask your IT Department if they can or will provide you with Split Tunneling.

Comment: I have also seen this before with split-tunneling being related to DNS or route precedent of the local routing table making everything go over VPN subnet. You should check the output of  `route print` connected and not connected to the VPN. So split tunneling on the VPN could resolve, so could routing differently if allowed and the VPN doesn't change or disconnect and at reconnect it'll update routing table. A misconfiguration can cause this too and sometimes you can workaround without split tunneling technically. Just some quick thoughts and ideas but starting with your VPN admin IT staff.

Comment: With or without, I have seen it both ways is what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

## Reasonable answer

You cannot configure this yourself and need to ask your IT to configure the VPN such that it only includes the corporate resources and excludes all other traffic. I've worked in an environment where this was configured by IT for all Skype traffic.

## Workaround with probably too much effort

If you can create virtual machines using Hyper-V you could roughly follow these steps:

1. Create a VM
2. Configure the corporate VPN inside the VM
3. Use the VM while connected to the VPN *from within* the VM
4. Do not connect the host machine to VPN and use it for things that don't require a VPN